# systemd service run on wireless network connect

Tags: networking, scripts, udev, systemd

I have a server that tries to connect to a mobile AP which is only sometimes available. This AP is a camera with images that need to be downloaded so the very second the server connects to this particular AP, I need it to run the download script (which I have already written).

I know I could do some very dirty polling but is there anything like the udev bridge in systemd? All my searching is bringing up very general networking stuff that doesn't quite apply. It's the scripting side of things that is key here.

<sub>Seconds after posting this it occurs that **it doesn't have to be systemd** if we have to do this just via `network-manager` (which is managing the wifi connection) then so be it... But this is for 15.10 with a view to deploy on 16.04 and I currently do this with Upstart on 14.04 so... I like whatever works but I also like neat and tidy.</sub>

Comment: Don't thank kos!  **;-)** If the answer below did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!  **>:-)**

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Network Manager dispatcher script to hook to the interface's up and down events.

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/00do_stuff
sudo chmod u+x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/00do_stuff
```

The script could go something along these lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 = wlp3s0f0 -a $2 = up -a $CONNECTION_ID = wlan ]; then
    # do stuff
fi
```

`man networkmanager` explains that if a dispatcher script runs for too long the script is killed at some point, so if that's a possibility it's better to fork another script to run the task:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 = wlp3s0f0 -a $2 = up -a $CONNECTION_ID = wlan ]; then
    (/home/user/scripts/do_stuff.sh) & disown
fi
```

Network Manager runs all the scripts in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` in alphabetical order each time certain events are triggered, passing the interface and the event as arguments.

`$CONNECTION_ID` is made available to the script through the environment, and in this case it's checked to make sure we're connected to the using the right connection profile as reported by `man networkprofile` (Not sure exactly what implications this has. In my case it works fine if I check `$CONNECTION_ID` against my SSID, but I'm not sure what would happen if this happened to match the name of another wired connection profile).